# Howto style a Resultpage of a Connector?

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, import.io

I have created a "connector" with a very nice tool called import.io which allows me to do a search inquiry by a other website and gets me an resultlist. I followed an other article by stackoverflow.com to do this:

[basic import.io html search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976303/basic-import-io-html-search/23990043#23990043)

This works well. But my question now:

How i style my HTML(Resultlist) with CSS like on this site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from your API into a web page you need to access the API via a programming language or script. Once you have the API return the Data as Json, you could try something like http://json2html.com/ to convert the Data into HTML and write that to your page.

Alternatively you could download the data as CSV, open it in excel and wrap html tags around the data and copy paste that into your website. its not idea, but at least you can get the data online.